# How can I correct the \pageref{LastPage} in this file?

Tags: lastpage

I use packages `lastpage` and  `answer` to make multiple choice. This is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=29cm, left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{%
Page \thepage\
 of \pageref{LastPage}}
\input{random}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \knuthshuffle_get_random:Nnn \setrannum

\tl_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl
\tl_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl
\int_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_random_int
\seq_new:N \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\inputpermutation}{mm}
 {% #1 is the number of files, #2 is the common prefix
  \knuthshuffle_generate:n { #1 }
  \ferrard_input:n { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \knuthshuffle_generate:n
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    \tl_clear_new:c { l_knuthshuffle_##1_element_tl }
    \tl_set:cn { l_knuthshuffle_##1_element_tl } { ##1 }
   }
  \prop_set_eq:NN \l_knuthshuffle_newperm_prop \g_knuthshuffle_identity_prop
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { -1 } { 2 }
   {
    \knuthshuffle_get_random:Nnn \l_knuthshuffle_random_int { 1 } { ##1 }
    \tl_set_eq:Nc \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl
     { l_knuthshuffle_##1_element_tl }
    \tl_set_eq:Nc \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl
     { l_knuthshuffle_ \int_to_arabic:n \l_knuthshuffle_random_int _element_tl }
    \tl_set_eq:cN { l_knuthshuffle_##1_element_tl }
     \l_knuthshuffle_tempb_tl
    \tl_set_eq:cN { l_knuthshuffle_ \int_to_arabic:n \l_knuthshuffle_random_int _element_tl }
     \l_knuthshuffle_tempa_tl
   }
  \seq_clear:N \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nv \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq { l_knuthshuffle_##1_element_tl }
   }
%  \seq_show:N \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq % for debugging
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ferrard_input:n #1
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_knuthshuffle_permutation_seq
   {
    \input{#1##1}\par
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\makeatletter
\newlength\choiceitemwidth
\newif\ifshowsolution \showsolutiontrue
\newcounter{choiceitem}
\def\thechoiceitem{\Alph{choiceitem}}
\def\makechoicelabel#1{#1\fbox{\thechoiceitem.}\else\thechoiceitem.\fi\space}
\def\choice@mesureitem#1{\cr\stepcounter{choiceitem}\makechoicelabel#1}
\def\choicemesureitem{\@ifstar
  {\choice@mesureitem\ifshowsolution}%
  {\choice@mesureitem\iffalse}}%
\def\choice@blockitem#1{%
  \ifnum\value{choiceitem}>0\hfil\fi
  \egroup\hskip0pt
  \hbox to \choiceitemwidth\bgroup\refstepcounter{choiceitem}\makechoicelabel#1}
\def\choiceblockitem{\@ifstar
  {\choice@blockitem\ifshowsolution}%
  {\choice@blockitem\iffalse}}
\def\choice@paraitem#1{%
  \par\refstepcounter{choiceitem}\makechoicelabel#1}
\def\choiceparaitem{\@ifstar
  {\choice@paraitem\ifshowsolution}%
  {\choice@paraitem\iffalse}}
\NewEnviron{choices}{%
  \begingroup
    \let\item\choicemesureitem
    \setcounter{choiceitem}{0}%
    \settowidth{\global\choiceitemwidth}{\vbox{\halign{##\hfil\cr\BODY\crcr}}}%
  \endgroup
  \trivlist\item\relax
  \parindent0pt
  \setcounter{choiceitem}{0}%
  \ifdim\choiceitemwidth<0.25\columnwidth
    \choiceitemwidth=0.25\columnwidth
    \let\item\choiceblockitem
    \bgroup\BODY\hfil\egroup
  \else\ifdim\choiceitemwidth<0.5\columnwidth
    \choiceitemwidth=0.5\columnwidth
    \let\item\choiceblockitem
    \bgroup\BODY\hfil\egroup
  \else % \choiceitemwidth > 0.5\columnwidth
    \let\item\choiceparaitem
    \BODY
  \fi\fi
  \endtrivlist
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{answers}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exame}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\renewcommand{\Solutionlabel}[1]{\textbf{Answer #1.}}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]
\setcounter{ex}{0}
\inputpermutation{2}{file}
\inputpermutation{2}{file}
\inputpermutation{2}{file}
\inputpermutation{2}{file}
\inputpermutation{2}{file}
\inputpermutation{2}{file}
\inputpermutation{2}{file}
\inputpermutation{2}{file}
\inputpermutation{2}{file}
\inputpermutation{2}{file}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\section{Solutions}
\input{ans1}
\end{document}
```

Here, file1.tex is

```
\begin{ex}
Find the correct answer
\begin{choices}
\item The first line.
\item The first line.
\item The first line.
\item* This is the answer.
\end{choices}
\begin{sol}
D
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
```

and file2.tex is

```
\begin{ex}
Find the correct answer
\begin{choices}
\item* This is the answer.
\item This is a quetion.
\item This is a quetion.
\item TThis is a quetion.
\end{choices}
\begin{sol}
A
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
```

I don't understand the \pageref{LastPage} dosn't correct.
[image]

How can I fix this case?

Comment: lastpage gives the `\pageref` to the last page of the document which is `1` here as you have `\setcounter{page}{1}` just before the solutions,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you very much. How can I fix it? Because, I want to make a newpage when I start a solutions.

Comment: it's not the newpage it's resetting the page counter to 1 I do not know the intention there if LasPage returned 3 (total page count) do you really want the final answer page to say page 1 of 3 ???? if not just remove the setcounter{page}

Comment: I don't want the final answer page to say page 1 of 3. I want to make a newpage when I start a solutions.

Comment: what _do_ you want it to say? page 1 of 1, or page 3 of 3? as I say newpage is not the problem, it is restarting the page counter to 1, why do that?

Comment: I am a teacher. I make to difference files. Some pages are questions and some pages are key of questions.  Pages are questions for my students. I page from 1 to Lastpage. Ex, there are 2 pages of questions, If I pages 3, it is not correct. Futhermore, I want to make many versions. Therefore, I setcounter many times.

Comment: sorry I do not understand that comment. currently you are restarting the page numbering from 1 when the solutions start so in this example the page numbers go 1,2,1 rather than 1,2,3. so what do you what the text to say??? presumably one of  "1 of 1, 1 of 2, 1 of 1"  or "1 of 3, 2 of 3, 3 of 3"  but which of these sequences do you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47331/discussion-between-toandhsp-and-david-carlisle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set a different label just before the solution sheet begins.

Here I present the bulk of the solution, you can add the rest: this highlights the solution, making it clear what's really necessary, so it can be useful also to other readers.

It's better to avoid “explicit” file names in the body of the document; so I define the answer file with `\AtBeginDocument` and create `\solutionsheet` next to it: editing will be easier.

The idea is that `\solutionsheet` emits a `\label` before doing the `\clearpage` and restarting numbering from 1. Instead of an explicit `\pageref` command in the footer, I use a macro that can be redefined by `\solutionsheet`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \lastpageref}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% normal value to be changed later
\newcommand{\lastpageref}{\pageref{LastPageOfQuestions}}

% for the solution sheet
\AtBeginDocument{\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]}
\newcommand{\solutionsheet}{%
  \label{LastPageOfQuestions}%
  \clearpage
  \renewcommand{\lastpageref}{\pageref{LastPage}}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
  \Closesolutionfile{ans}%
  \section{Solutions}%
  \input{ans1}%
}

\begin{document}

Page of questions 1

\clearpage

Page of questions 2

\solutionsheet

\end{document}
```

For several question sheets with the attached solution pages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \lastpageref}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% normal value to be changed later
\newcommand{\lastpageref}{\pageref{LastPageOfQuestions\totalquestionsheets}}
\let\questionpageref\lastpageref

\newcounter{questionsheet}
\regtotcounter{questionsheet}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \edef\totalquestionsheets{%
    \@ifundefined{c@questionsheet@totc}{0}{\the\totvalue{questionsheet}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\questionsheet}{%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
  \let\lastpageref\questionpageref
  \stepcounter{questionsheet}%
  \Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans\thequestionsheet]%
}
\newcommand{\solutionsheet}{%
  \label{LastPageOfQuestions\thequestionsheet}%
  \clearpage
  \ifnum\totalquestionsheets=\value{questionsheet}
    \renewcommand{\lastpageref}{\pageref{LastPage}}%
  \else
    \renewcommand{\lastpageref}{\pageref{LastPageOfAnswers\thequestionsheet}}%
  \fi
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
  \Closesolutionfile{ans}%
  \section{Solutions}%
  \input{ans\thequestionsheet}%
  \label{LastPageOfAnswers\thequestionsheet}
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}

\questionsheet

Page of questions 1

\clearpage

Page of questions 2

\solutionsheet

\questionsheet

Page of questions 3

\clearpage

Page of questions 4

\solutionsheet

\end{document}
```

This will print

- Page 1 of 2
- Page 2 of 2
- Page 1 of 1
- Page 1 of 2
- Page 2 of 2
- Page 1 of 1

Alternatively, for numbering consecutively the question sheets

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \lastpageref}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

% normal value to be changed later
\newcommand{\lastpageref}{\pageref{LastPageOfQuestions\totalquestionsheets}}
\let\questionpageref\lastpageref

\newcounter{questionsheet}
\regtotcounter{questionsheet}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \edef\totalquestionsheets{%
    \@ifundefined{c@questionsheet@totc}{0}{\the\totvalue{questionsheet}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{savepage}

\newcommand{\questionsheet}{%
  \let\lastpageref\questionpageref
  \stepcounter{questionsheet}%
  \Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans\thequestionsheet]%
}
\newcommand{\solutionsheet}{%
  \label{LastPageOfQuestions\thequestionsheet}%
  \clearpage
  \ifnum\totalquestionsheets=\value{questionsheet}
    \renewcommand{\lastpageref}{\pageref{LastPage}}%
  \else
    \renewcommand{\lastpageref}{\pageref{LastPageOfAnswers\thequestionsheet}}%
  \fi
  \setcounter{savepage}{\value{page}}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
  \Closesolutionfile{ans}%
  \section{Solutions}%
  \input{ans\thequestionsheet}%
  \label{LastPageOfAnswers\thequestionsheet}
  \clearpage
  \ifnum\totalquestionsheets=\value{questionsheet}
  \else
    \setcounter{page}{\value{savepage}}
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\questionsheet

Page of questions 1

\clearpage

Page of questions 2

\solutionsheet

\questionsheet

Page of questions 3

\clearpage

Page of questions 4

\solutionsheet

\end{document}
```

This will print

- Page 1 of 4
- Page 2 of 4
- Page 1 of 1
- Page 3 of 4
- Page 4 of 4
- Page 1 of 1

Comment: If I want to make many versions of questions and its answer.  I tried 

Page of questions 1

\clearpage

Page of questions 2

\solutionsheet


Page of questions 3

\clearpage

Page of questions 4

\solutionsheet

It is not correct. Please help me.

Comment: @toandhsp I'll work on it. Stay tuned.

Comment: @toandhsp Just to get it right: you have something like “page 1, page 2, solutions, page 3, page 4, solutions,” and the pages of questions should have “Page n of 4”?

Comment: I am sorry. Last night, I went to bed. I want to have “page 1, page 2, solutions, page 1, page 2, solutions, page 1, page 2, solutions,..

Comment: @toandhsp Now *I* am going to bed. Stay tuned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47362/discussion-between-toandhsp-and-egreg).

Comment: @toandhsp New solution on line